# How to select v-radio by clicking on v-list item vue + vuetify

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

The problem:
I'm trying to select a radio button by clicking on a list item.

In vuetify manual, this is achieved with a checkbox statically
[#9 Action with title and sub-title](https://vuetifyjs.com/releases/0.17/#/components/lists)

My jsfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/tgpfhn8m/

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="app">
   <template>
      <div>
         <v-list two-line>
            <v-radio-group :mandatory="true" v-model="selectedItem">
               <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
                  <v-list-tile @click="itemType({'name': item.name, 'id':item.id })">
                     <v-list-tile-action>
                        <v-radio :value="item.name" :key="item.id"
                           ></v-radio>
                     </v-list-tile-action>
                     <v-list-tile-content>
                        <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.name }}</v-list-tile-title>
                        <v-list-tile-sub-title>{{ item.description }}</v-list-tile-sub-title>
                     </v-list-tile-content>
                  </v-list-tile>
               </template>
            </v-radio-group>
         </v-list>
      </div>
   </template>
</div>


Vue.use(Vuetify);
    const items = [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'James',
            description: "If you don't succeed, dust yourself off and try again.",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Fatima',
            description: 'Better late than never but never late is better.',
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Xin',
            description: 'Beauty in the struggle, ugliness in the success.',
        }
    ]
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            items,
            selectedItem: '',
        },
        methods: {
            itemType(payload) {
                //this.$store.commit('item/setIteminStore', payload)
            }
        }
    })
```

What is the best way to achieve this dynamically with a radio?

Noting that: Clicking around the radio button selects the radio but not on the list item.

> Using vue@2.5.9, vuetify@ 0.17.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use onclick to set the selected.

```
itemType(payload) {
    this.selectedItem = payload.name
}
```

and use watch to store the item for either the user click te radio button or list item the store function is called like this :

```
watch: {
        selectedItem (val) {
        console.log(val)
        this.$store.commit('item/setIteminStore', payload)
      }
    },
```

i have make the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zacuwyw3/2/

Comment: Thank you!. Works beautifully as expected!

Comment: so you are using `vuetify@0.14.8` and `vue@2.4.2`, strange enough your code works for these, but does not work for my version `vue@2.5.9, vuetify@ 0.17.1`

Comment: I did poke around and the issue is with vuetify@0.17.1- radios needed to be direct children.  It was fixed in later versions. Comparing (https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v0.17.1/src/components/VRadioGroup/VRadioGroup.js#L65-L68 to) (https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v1.0.14/src/components/VRadioGroup/VRadioGroup.js#L17). I did a little editing on where the v-model should be placed, but out of that, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Solution for `@vuetify 0.17.7` : https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/300244/ and your solution for `@vuetify0.14.8` : https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/300244/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know vuetify. But the solution will be similar.

Below is one pure Vue sample to implement what you need. I think it can be transplanted to vuetify easily.

It is simple, just bind `:checked` of `<input type="radio">` with `"team === selectedTeam"`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#boxes',
  data: {
    checked: null,
    //checkedNames: [],
    teams: [{'text':'team1', 'field':'team1'},{'text':'team2', 'field':'team2'},{'text':'team3', 'field':'team3'}],
    selectedTeam: null
  },
  methods: {
    selectOneTeam: function (team) {
      this.selectedTeam = team
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id='boxes'>
<div>
  <div>
    <p>What you selected:</p>
    <a v-for="(team, index) in teams" :key="index">
    <span>{{team.text}}:</span>
    <input type="radio" name="team" :checked="team === selectedTeam"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(team, index) in teams" :key="index" style="width: 100px; float:left" @click="selectOneTeam(team)">
      {{team.text}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

Comment: I did try it with my setup but it didn't give the desired results?